# alignment issue with similar devices

Tags: html, css

I have a website which I am hosting at [www.upcani.com](http://www.upcani.com), there is an alignment issue which I'm getting feedback for.

I have a table and it is shifting towards the right, even if I am using the same system as another user, we are seeing 2 different things

the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXtdR.jpg

what it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP5gB.jpg

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, this is occurring for quite a bit of users

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is delete the width: 90vw; from your table tag and it will pop into the center of the page.

Comment: wait so that was it? I was converting to a div, that saved me a lot of time, thanks